# Window Service Bus read performance counters from the performance monitor

Tags: c#, azure, servicebus, azureservicebus

Hy,

I found the performance counters on the following side:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj192996.aspx

You can check the performance counters with the Perfomance pane in the Windows Performance Monitor, that works fine. I need two of the performance counter for my application. Does somebody know how I can access the performance counters in my c# application?

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hy,

I solved it in Visual Studio you have the Server Explorer in there you can read all the performance counters which are available. The performance counters are below Servers and then choose your computer name.

Best regards